# Voronoi-Lloyd ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, array, geometry

[Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) is a partition of a plane (or part of plane) into regions close to each of a given set of objects ("seeds").
Here we’ll be dealing with discrete arrays or even rather with ASCII-art:

```
2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
2 2 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Since it is not difficult to draw a discrete Voronoi diagram, we will go a little further and
consider [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm).

##### Short description

It repeatedly finds the centroid of each cell in the Voronoi partition and then re-partitions the input according to which of these centroids is closest.
The process converges quickly to a certain precision, but for real numbers formally infinitely long.
For integer coordinates the process should always stop.

To find Voronoi cells you can use any of the algorithms of several known.
Like just brutal-force tagging with nearest seed, or something [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_flooding_algorithm).

It seems that with the next distance functions process will be converge
(but I have no math proof):

- SquaredEuclidean distance
- Euclidean distance
- [Chessboard (Chebyshev) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)
- [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)
- [Canberra distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canberra_distance)

Probably with slightly different visual results. You can use any distance that is suitable for golfing in your language.

##### Challenge

Print out ASCII art as a result of Lloyd's algorithm for given initial seeds.

##### Input

- Width `W` and height `H` of the board. Integers `W, H > 0` and not very big (no more than `100` I think)
- Initial array of seeds as explicit list of coordinates:
  `[[4,5], [1,1], …]`
- Number of seeds (as length of array) `N` should be `0 < N < 10`
  (for not to break print formatting)

##### Output

Final state of Lloyd's process as a pretty-printed array of ASCII strings, where `"0"` is used for any seed and `"1"..."9"` digits for filling corresponding cells.
Might be interesting to print firstly initial state.

##### Test cases

The main test is that the code is not broken in obvious cases, for example:

```
Input: W:2, H:2, initial seeds: [[1,1]]  
Output:  
01   
11
```

```
Input: W:10, H:1, initial seeds:[[1, 1], [2, 1]]  
Output:  
1011220222
```

Simple program on Mathematica 12.2 was used for samples.
With [`ChessboardDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChessboardDistance.html?q=ChessboardDistance) as distance function,
[`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) as core for Voronoi tessellation and [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html), `Floor@Mean@Position` combination for Lloyd relaxation.

```
Input: W:13, H:10, initial seeds: [[2, 3], [4, 7], [8, 8], [9, 11]]
```

Initial Voronoi partition:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 2 2 2 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
1 2 2 2 3 3 3 0 3 4 4 4 4
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 0 4 4
2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Result of the Lloyd process:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4
1 1 0 1 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 4 4
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4
1 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 0 4 4
3 3 3 0 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

As challenge is not very difficult, it is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and shortest code wins.

Comment: I assume we can choose whether the input-coordinates are 1-based or 0-based indexed? Also, I don't really understand the seeds in the test cases, because `[[1,1]]` in the first test case would be either the top-left if 1-based indexing is used or bottom-right if 0-based indexing is used. But instead, the output has a `0` at index `[1,2]` (1-based) / `[0,1]` (0-based). Likewise I also don't get how coordinate `[2,1]` can result in a `0` at the 6th position of the 1x10 output-block.

Comment: @kevin-cruijssen,  I use Mathematica top-left [1,1] notation, and surely possible to use any other. I fix first example. What about second, the output is _the result_ of Lloyd process, not just initial Voronoi partition!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I think [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwVrG.png) is what OP is doing iteratively where x == seeds coördinates. When seeds don't change nomore (partition stabalized), output zero at seeds position. Note seed [2,1] should be read as [column, row] but for consistant readability should be changed to [1,2] as the 1st dimension in an array should be the row notation.

Comment: @lesobrod, would you mind include the initial seeds you have used for your final sample? Would be interesting to see the deviation between your answer and the applied algorithms in given answers.

Comment: It seems we need to use _Lloyd's algorithm_ but then you say "to find Voronoi cells you can use _any of the algorithms of several known_". Can you clarify? Also, you say "it is also interesting to play with various distance functions". What distance function/funtions must/can the answer use? Lastly, some more test cases would be convenient.

Comment: Post totally edited according to comments!

Comment: My VTC stands as it's still unclear to me what's being asked of us. You're relying heavily on prior knowledge and external sources, which are at risk of link rot, instead of presenting a self-contained challenge.

Comment: You say we can use any distance function.  What do you consider a "distance function"? I'd normally assume you mean a metric, but this includes the discrete metric which would pretty much wreck this challenge.

Comment: Also what do we do in the case of ties, i.e. which cell is a position in when it is equally distant from two seeds?

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear for the reasons I listed above.  While I think this challenge should rely less on external links, I don't think it's an major obstacle to clarity, since the links provide widely known mathematical terminology.  Even if the links rot or die, the content can be found elsewhere with a simple search.

Answer (score 8):

## Excel (ms365), 542 bytes

Using [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), here is an iterative example where `W==10`, `H==1` and seeds are `[[1, 1], [1, 2]]` (note the appropriate row, column notation):

**1st Seeds/Partition**:

The 1st seeds are given in `R1:S2`. So we just need to create the 1st partition. In Excel this was doable using the following formula in `A1`:

```
=MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,BYROW(ABS(R1:S2-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),MATCH(MIN(x),x,0))))
```

[image]

**2nd Seeds/Partition**:

After this initial partition we need to iterate all possible group of digits 1-9 and find it's centroid ([Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm)). In Excel to find the centroid and make it applicable for the next iteration we can use an average of each cell's respective row and column. In my case I choose to round down any figure to find the position of the next centroid:

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUND(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(A1#,r,c)=y,r,NA()))),2)),0))),2),TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUND(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(A1#,r,c)=y,c,NA()))),2)),0))),2))
```

This would return: `[[1,1],[1,6]]`

**Final Seeds/Partition:**

For a 2nd partition, we can use the formula from the 1st partition but need a way to swap the hardcoded `R1:S2` out with the formentioned results. For this we need an iterative `LAMBDA()` function that we can feed results as we go. One option could be `REDUCE()`. Since OP stated that there are no more rows/column than a 100 we can iterate 99 times (Excel's performance will take a big hit here though):

```
=REDUCE(R1:S2,ROW(1:99),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(z,MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,BYROW(ABS(a-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),MATCH(MIN(x),x,0)))),HSTACK(TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,r,NA()))),2)),0))),2),TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,c,NA()))),2)),0))),2)))))
```

This will give us the final seeds `[[1,2],[1,7]]` which in return can be used in the formula we created in the 1st partition:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,BYROW(ABS(REDUCE(R1:S2,ROW(1:99),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(z,MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,BYROW(ABS(a-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),MATCH(MIN(x),x,0)))),HSTACK(TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,r,NA()))),2)),0))),2),TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,c,NA()))),2)),0))),2)))))-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),MATCH(MIN(x),x,0))))
```

**Final [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram):**

What is left to do is to change the cells that hold the last known centroid's positions into a zero. For this we need to nest an `IF()` to check this requirement. The final result looks like:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(q,REDUCE(R1:S2,ROW(1:99),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(z,MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,BYROW(ABS(a-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),MATCH(MIN(x),x,0)))),HSTACK(TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,r,NA()))),2)),0))),2),TOCOL(MAP(ROW(1:9),LAMBDA(y,ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(V2,V1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(INDEX(z,r,c)=y,c,NA()))),2)),0))),2))))),x,BYROW(ABS(q-HSTACK(r,c)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(TAKE(q,,1)=r)*(DROP(q,,1)=c),0)),0,MATCH(MIN(x),x,0)))))
```

---

**Other results:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

<sup>**Famous Quote:** *"As challenge is not very difficult..."*([Lesobrod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114511/lesobrod), 2023).</sup>

Comment: I'm 100% sure this can be done using fewer bytes (in any other language/application), but at this point I'm just happy that I could achieve this using Excel functions.

Comment: This is a first answer to my first question on CD so many, many thanks and best wishes!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 79 bytes

```
Ｗ¬⁼ζυ«≔ζυ≔ＥθＥＥηＥζ⌈↔Ｅξ⁻ρ⎇ςμκ⌕μ⌊με≔ＥζＥ⟦ＥεＥ№μλνＥε⌕Ａμλ⟧÷ΣΣμＬΣμζ»Ｆζ§≔§ε§ι⁰⊟ι±¹Ｅ⊕ε⪫ι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZFLTsMwEIbFkp5ilJUtXKmhSBR1FfGQiqCqVHZRFmniNhaO3fpRShBrDsGmiyK4EpwGO25ZEMn5xzPzz2fL719FlatC5ny7_bBm3h38HL09VYxTQGNp0PXK5lyjhoDFGMNL5zjRmi1EyAz_tvf5Eq0IePGrCmHjZcNqW6NkpiW3hrbljcszYTVSBB6oErl6RmsCNYFHHD4CN0yUqG4b2wF1SNN_0CaQUv-jIb6UVhhv5a5feNO-6EcmnIcSzgiMhLlia1ZSNHWEaaAQuKNiYarDvsU2DvvamUsFqMEQ-IkZiZJu0EEd4RAyAj1vm8glYk7HdJG7u8fYjZko5o7njzQShaI1FYaWiLquW8mEt0YQOehwp2eF3r_KZxp11zzKvk_SuEcg7hNI01MCfXeL9IzAudcBgYHXC9cQZ1kWrL8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ¬⁼ζυ«
```

Repeat until the process stabilises.

```
≔ζυ
```

Save the previous seeds.

```
≔ＥθＥＥηＥζ⌈↔Ｅξ⁻ρ⎇ςμκ⌕μ⌊με
```

For each cell in the matrix, calculate the nearest 0-indexed seed according to the chessboard distance, using the earlier seed in the event of a tie.

```
≔ＥζＥ⟦ＥεＥ№μλνＥε⌕Ａμλ⟧÷ΣΣμＬΣμζ
```

Calculate the centroids of the regions using integer arithmetic (so the results are always truncated).

```
»Ｆζ§≔§ε§ι⁰⊟ι±¹
```

Set the cells with seeds to `-1`.

```
Ｅ⊕ε⪫ι
```

Increment the cells to make them 1-indexed and output the final Voronoi diagram.

80 bytes to output the diagram at each step:

```
Ｗ¬⁼ζυ«≔ζυ≔ＥθＥＥηＥζ⌈↔Ｅξ⁻ρ⎇ςμκ⌕μ⌊με≔ＥζＥ⟦ＥεＥ№μλνＥε⌕Ａμλ⟧÷ΣΣμＬΣμζＦυ§≔§ε§κ⁰§κ¹±¹⟦Ｅ⊕ε⪫κ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVHLSsNAFMWlfsUlqxmcQmMFK66CD6hoEXQXskiTaTN0MrHzqDXiT7h104Wiv6Rf49xMK2IgOfdxzj13Jq-fRZXrosnlev3u7LQ3_N55eaiE5EDGjSXnC5dLQ1oGjlIKT3u7iTFipkLl5De9zu_JggECvlUIW4SVqF1NkolppLO8a698XShniGZwx7XK9SNZMqgZzGl4GFwIVZK6I3YD6lDm_0zb4JTih4f4tHHKolR6vkLRpokjEylDi2YMRsqeiaUoObn1DrfBhcEVVzNbbfPOtkXbaaOBOArBPrEjVfIV2aI32IZzBn1U_cljn475LPc3EFMcdqOF37Lbe6QKzWuuLC8J97zLRijURBD5NT35-c1MCrP5QR9p1FvKKPvaT-O-HzxgkKYHDAb-QOkhgyPEIYMh4rEnxFmWBekP) Link is to verbose version of code.

Note that if I added multidimensional indexing to Charcoal then both solutions would be 76 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 184 bytes

```
(s=#1;w=#2;h=#3;r=Range@Length@s;b=Array[0&,{h,w}];v=(Do[b[[i,j]]=First@Nearest[#->r,{i,j}],{i,h},{j,w}];⌊Mean@Position[b,#]⌋&/@r)&;s=FixedPoint[v@#&,s];Print@ReplacePart[b,s->0])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBagIxGIRfZSEQFH5xt7YUCZEUSk@2LF5DDv9qNJGaLUlQS8gLtD6lL7LN9jB8MwwzJ4xGnzDaLQ57PkwCJw27cPLADCcL5vkG3UGLtXaHaERgHX/xHr9lTSEZuGTFznzy2stOSgtHpfib9SGKD41ehyjJbOUhlSarESZDOv6v7refd41OtH2w0fZOdkDU/fZL58JPKQvl56p3bW9dlGdBKATFWl@S2OivT9zqFn0sozBb1WpKh71MqYFqkaFKj1A9jXyGapmLaepRavgD)

I am sorry that this challenge caused such a misunderstanding. Perhaps the problem is my bad English.
Here is a short version for Mathematica (and sure should be more golfed!).
It uses `EuclideanDistance` (as it's default for `Nearest`) and output only final state. All this is acceptable for other answers.
Unfortunately TIO does not understand pretty-print operators WM like `TableForm` and `MatrixForm`.
But I know that for many languages TIO works well, so I believe that eg Vyxal ASCII-art version should be less than 100 bytes (-_0)

Maybe this full-named and commented version will be useful.

```
print[{board_, seeds_}] := TableForm[
   ReplacePart[board, seeds -> 0], TableSpacing -> {0, 0.5}
   ];

lloyd[initSeeds_, w_, h_] := With[
   {dist = ChessboardDistance,
    numSeeds = Length@initSeeds
    },
   (*Initialize board with background 0 and seeds*)
   board = 
    Normal@SparseArray[
      Table[initSeeds[[i]] -> i, {i, numSeeds}], {h, w}];

   (*Lambda where # stands for seeds, but board also updated*)
   voronoi =
    (Do[
       (*Update board, 
       tagging every position with it's closest seed index*)
       board[[i, j]] = First@Nearest[# -> Range@numSeeds, {i, j}]
       , {i, h}, {j, w}];
      (*Return new seeds as centroids of every cells*)
      Table[Floor@Mean@Position[board, k], {k, numSeeds}]) &;

   (*Repeat voronoi until result no longer changed*)
   seeds = FixedPoint[voronoi@# &, initSeeds];
   (*Output board and final seeds*)
   {board, seeds}
   ];
```